# Magento2 override Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml

Tags: magento2, swatches

Magento2 how I am supposed to override `renderer.phtml` of module swatches?

I have already tried `Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml`, but doesn't seem to be working?

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you put your overrid file?

Comment: in the theme folder

Comment: if you have added in `app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml` then it should work. Please confirm

Comment: Thanks @ShoaibMunir it worked. I forgot to add templates in between

Comment: Great, I am adding this in answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you have added your file in this location

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Swatches/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

But you can override from your custom module. Need create Module with sequence Magento_Swatches and create file in similar location app/code/Namespace/Module/view/templates/product/listing/renderer.phtml